# How can i set formControlName (in HTML) to control inside formArray nested 3 times?

Tags: angular

So I just can't figure this one out. My FormGroup looks like this:

```
templateForm = new FormGroup({
    title: new FormControl(),
    description: new FormControl(),
    items: new FormArray([
    new FormGroup({
        type: new FormControl('table'),
        rows: new FormArray([
            new FormGroup({
                    header: new FormControl(''),
                    values: new FormArray([
                        new FormControl('Test')
                    ])
                })
        ])
        })])
  });
```

Html:

```html
<div *ngSwitchCase="'table'">
                    <table>
                      <thead>
                        <tr class="row">
                          <th class="col s2 m2 l2" *ngFor="let row of item.controls.rows.controls; index as rowIndex">
                            <a (click)="removeTableRow(i, rowIndex)" class="rmRow btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="small material-icons">remove</i></a>
                          </th>
                          <th>
                            <a (click)="addTableRow(i)" class="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light blue"><i class="small material-icons">add</i></a>
                          </th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <thead>
                        <tr class="row">
                          <th class="col s2 m2 l2" *ngFor="let row of item.controls.rows.controls; index as y">
                            <div formArrayName="rows">
                              <form [formGroup]="row" novalidate>
                                <input type="text" formControlName="header">
                              </form>
                            </div>
                          </th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr class="row" *ngFor="let column of item.controls.rows.controls[0].controls.values.controls; index as y">
                          <div class="col s2 m2 l2" *ngFor="let row of item.controls.rows.controls">
                            <div *ngFor="let value of row.controls.values.controls; let valI = index">
                              <div formArrayName="values" >
                                <input type="text" [formControlName]="valI">
                              </div> !! How to set value in values array to formControl !!
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
```

My goal is to display a table, the height of the number of columns in the first row. Now I just can't figure out how to set formControl in HTML to control in formArray in formArray in formArray (yeah a few in's).

Comment: At first glance, it appears you have the inner `[formGroup]` directives after the formArrayName messed up. Think of it as if you are navigating down the properties of the form object. When you do formArrayName, it points to an array so you then need to give it the index of the array as the next formGroup. But it also looks like the data is not setup optimally which I assume the limited context doesn't explain. I.E. I can't see why items is a FormArray or how you are getting the `item` variable name in your `*ngFor`s or why values is a FormArray and not just a FormGroup of an object.

Comment: please provide a [mcve] This is not reproducable as it sits. Best would be to create a **minimal** reproduction in a stackblitz.

Comment: Divide the problem. 1.-create a json object with real data, 2.think about create a formGroup or not (if you only want to show data, you needn't a FormGroup),3.-begings with some simple as `<pre>{{myForm.?.value|json}}</pre>